# How do I manage the data binding

Tags: vb.net, listview, datasource

I have a listview which only call the data binding once the parameters need is complete. So when the button[Find] is click, it will first provide the parameters, then call the method that will data bind the listview. Now my problem is, on the listview, like each row in the listview, a user can click a link button to view what the row details to another page. Apparently, once I close the page and go back the first page, the data bind is lose. Should I always rebind every action I take on the first page?

Comment: When the user clicks the link, do the details appear pop up, or replace the current window? If it's a popup, the window should stay the same. But if the first page refreshes, then yes, you ought to rebind it, if that is how data is displayed.

Comment: Not really sure there is enough info here to help sorry.  Without understanding a lot more about exactly what you're doing with bindings, datasources and filtering and in what platform everything is just guessing.

Comment: Please specify the technology you're using, as there are multiple controls named `ListView`. My first guess was WPF but when you talk about pages it sounds like a web app.

Comment: Hi it's a web app, I just put my data binding for list view on page rendering, I guess that solves my problem.